# Minification is not working even Magento is set to Production mode

Tags: js-css, minify

Currently, we are using Magento 2.2.6. I have enabled the Minify and merge js and css via admin panel configuration but the minification is not working.

I have read many posts about the very same issue which I'm facing and done all the suggestions they have given but still not getting the result.

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Have you get  any solution about Minify and merge js in Production mode?

Comment: I have followed many suggestions which are posted in Stack Exchange but still not working. If you have any solution for this issue, kindly let me know.

Comment: Could you find any solution @Siva ?

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade

bin/magento indexer:reindex

bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s

# Here was the secret: run the di:compile after production
bin/magento setup:di:compile  

bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```